# Convert RLE to a string in Python from a list

Tags: python, run-length-encoding

I have adapted a piece of code from another question that converts a string to RLE in Python. I am looking for a solution that uses the same concept, but in reverse, i.e. entering some RLE and getting a complete string back. I have included the original code I used below.

Thanks in advance (updated to include contributed code and screenshot of output)

```
text=input("Please enter the string to encode")
encoded=[]
index=0
amount=1
while index<=(len(text)-1):  
  if index==(len(text)-1) or text[index]!=text[(index+1)]:
    encoded.append((text[index],amount))        
    amount=1
  else:
    amount=amount+1            
  index=index+1   
print(encoded)

from itertools import groupby

def rle(text):
    return [(i, len(list(g))) for i, group in groupby(text)]

def from_rle(s):
    return ''.join((i*j for i, j in s))

print(text)


[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLevj.jpg][1]
```

Comment: For anyone confused by RLE: Run-length encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: Please add whatever attempts you have made till now

Answer (score 0):

try to use groupby

```
from itertools import groupby

def rle(text):
    return [(i, len(list(g))) for i, group in groupby(text)]

def from_rle(s):
    return ''.join((i*j for i, j in s))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have added this to the above code and entered some test data, but I'm not sure that I'm getting the desired result. I would like to enter something like a2b2c2 and get an output of aabbcc.

Comment: use re pattern： `''.join((i*int(j) for i, j in re.findall('(.*?)(\d+)', 'a2b2c2')))`

Comment: Thanks.I've tried and seem to get the same result
`from itertools import groupby

def rle(text):
    return [(i, len(list(g))) for i, group in groupby(text)]

def from_rle(s):
    return ''.join((i*int(j) for i, j in re.findall('(.*?)(\d+)', 'a2b2c2')))
            
text=input("Please enter the string to encode")
encoded=[]
index=0
amount=1
while index<=(len(text)-1):  
  if index==(len(text)-1) or text[index]!=text[(index+1)]:
    encoded.append((text[index],amount))        
    amount=1
    
  else:
    amount=amount+1            
  index=index+1   

print(encoded)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line

```
''.join([x*y for x,y in encoded])
```

With this you iterate over the list and create a list with strings with their respective occurence. Then you joint this lists to get it as a single String.